# Inherit a class but only use required fields ,not all inherited fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Suppose there are total 3 class. **A**,**B** and **C**.

```
class A(models.Model):
    one = models.IntegerField()
    two = models.IntegerField()
    three = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class B(A):
    pass 

class C(A):
   pass
```

I am inheriting the **class A** in **B** and **C**,but i want to use only fields **one** and **two** in **classB** while all the three fields in **classC**.

Is it possible to inherit some fields of **classA** in **classB** and some in **classC**?

or is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may already know, there are three types of [inheritance across models in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance).

> 1. Often, you will just want to use the parent class to hold information that you don’t want to have to type out for each child model. This class isn’t going to ever be used in isolation, so Abstract base classes are what you’re after.
> 2. If you’re subclassing an existing model (perhaps something from another application entirely) and want each model to have its own database table, Multi-table inheritance is the way to go.
> 3. Finally, if you only want to modify the Python-level behavior of a model, without changing the models fields in any way, you can use Proxy models.

The only choice for your use-case is `abstract base classes`.

And the thing you are looking for [from docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes):

> Fields inherited from abstract base classes can be overridden with another field or value, or be removed with None.

So you should have:

```
class A(models.Model):
    one = models.IntegerField()
    two = models.IntegerField()
    three = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class B(A):
    three = None


class C(A):
    three = None
```

And to answer your second question, It's not a bad idea; We normally use it when we want to change the `USERNAME_FIELD` while extending django's default user model.